# Hybris, how to load the cart using cartId

Tags: cart, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a requirement, where the customer can share the cart via email, in Hybris how to load the cart using cartId?

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these:

de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.order.CommerceCartService

- CartModel getCartForGuidAndSiteAndUser(String guid, BaseSiteModel site, UserModel user)
- CartModel getCartForGuidAndSite(String guid, BaseSiteModel site)
- CartModel getCartForCodeAndUser(String code, UserModel user)